# SUBSTR and INSTR issue with multi-bytes characters in an UTF-8 encoded database

Tags: sql, sqlite, unicode, utf-8

Edit: solved by nbk in a comment, go to the end for the answer

I have an UTF-8 encoded SQLite database where SUBSTR seems to behave as working with bytes instead of working with characters, rendering it mostly useless. I don't know if I stumbled upon a SQLite bug/limitation or if there is some syntax to coerce SUBSTR to do the right thing. I'm trying to extract a substring with the end computed by INSTR(). INSTR() seems to return results based on the character (Unicode codepoint), while SUBSTR() seems to work on bytes, rendering it mostly useless with UTF-8.

Here is an very reduced test case exhibiting the issue :

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE test (title TEXT);
INSERT INTO test VALUES(X'3232313031315f313335365f417072c3a8732d6d6964695f31312d31302d32303232220d');
INSERT INTO test VALUES(X'3232313031335f313535315f5f5245504f52544147455f31372d30312d32303230220d');
COMMIT;
```

Relevant informations:

```
sqlite> .version
SQLite 3.26.0 2018-12-01 12:34:55 bf8c1b2b7a5960c282e543b9c293686dccff272512d08865f4600fb58238alt1
zlib version 1.2.11
gcc-8.3.1 20191121 (Red Hat 8.3.1-5)
sqlite> PRAGMA encoding;
UTF-8
sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE test (title TEXT);
sqlite> select * from test;
221011_1356_Après-midi_11-10-2022"
221013_1551__REPORTAGE_17-01-2020"
```

The two strings are the same character length (same number of Unicode codepoints) but the first one is one byte (octet) longer due to the presence of the 'è' character encoded with two bytes.

The following query shows INSTR() considering characters, and SUBSTR() working on bytes. (The query is attempting to strip the extra '"' at the end, but end up cutting too much in the presence of multi-bytes characters.

This makes using SUBSTR() on boundaries computed by INSTR() unusable in the presence of multi-bytes characters.

```
sqlite> select INSTR(title, '"'), SUBSTR(title, 0, INSTR(title, '"')) from test;
34|221011_1356_Après-midi_11-10-202
34|221013_1551__REPORTAGE_17-01-2020
```

Is there a way to make SUBSTR() and INSTR() play together nicely?

For the record, same but under Windows with the latest version at the time, 3.41.2

```
SQLite version 3.41.2 2023-03-22 11:56:21
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> .schema
sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
sqlite> BEGIN TRANSACTION;
sqlite> CREATE TABLE test (title TEXT);
sqlite> INSERT INTO test VALUES(X'3232313031315f313335365f417072c3a8732d6d6964695f31312d31302d32303232220d');
sqlite> INSERT INTO test VALUES(X'3232313031335f313535315f5f5245504f52544147455f31372d30312d32303230220d');
sqlite> COMMIT;
sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE test (title TEXT);
sqlite> .version
SQLite 3.41.2 2023-03-22 11:56:21 0d1fc92f94cb6b76bffe3ec34d69cffde2924203304e8ffc4155597af0c191da
zlib version 1.2.11
gcc-5.2.0
sqlite> PRAGMA encoding;
UTF-8
sqlite> select * from test;
221011_1356_Après-midi_11-10-2022"
221013_1551__REPORTAGE_17-01-2020"
sqlite> select INSTR(title, '"'), SUBSTR(title, 0, INSTR(title, '"')) from test;
34|221011_1356_Après-midi_11-10-202
34|221013_1551__REPORTAGE_17-01-2020
sqlite> select INSTR(cast(title as varchar), '"'), SUBSTR(cast(title as varchar), 0, INSTR(cast(title as varchar), '"')) from test; -- nbk solved it, the key is casting to varchar for SUBSTR to work properly it seems
34|221011_1356_Après-midi_11-10-2022
34|221013_1551__REPORTAGE_17-01-2020
```

Comment: i really can't reproduce your error https://dbfiddle.uk/ujVXe1SA  why do you even want to enter the tile in that manner

Comment: This is a simplified version and I didn't make the dataset I'm just cleaning it

Comment: It's extremely odd, I just reproduced it on 3.41.2 under Windows so it's not tied to the slightly old version I'm stuck with under Linux. No idea why it seems to work in the fiddle.

Comment: have you tried the convert to varchar also like in the link?

Comment: That did it! (I misunderstood the first time and changed TEXT top VARCHAR in the schema which had no effect). What kind of sorcery is this ? I'll gladly upvote that as an answer.

Comment: That begs the question, why are the casts needed?

Comment: There is no varchar data type in SQLite: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html I suspect that the problem in your case is that you insert BLOBs and not TEXT.

Comment: That would explain why the DB dump used hex instead of regular text. The app that inserted the data must not have done it quite right. SQLite dynamic typing not being so friendly here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source of your problem is that you have defined the column `title` as `TEXT` but you insert `BLOB` values.

It is clearly documented in Datatypes In [SQLite/Column Affinity Behavior Example](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#column_affinity_behavior_example):

> BLOBs are always stored as BLOBs regardless of column affinity.

This means that you if you insert `BLOB`s you will also get `BLOB`s in `SELECT` statements which *may* or *may not* be converted to `TEXT` when used with SQLite's string functions, depending on the documented behavior of each function for treating `BLOB`s.

Here is the description of `SUBSTR()`'s behavior:

> The substr(X,Y,Z) function returns a substring of input string X that
> begins with the Y-th character and which is Z characters long.
>
> ............
>
> If X is a string then characters indices refer to actual UTF-8
> characters.
>
> If X is a BLOB then the indices refer to **bytes**.

So, there is nothing strange about the results that you get and the best that you could do is recreate the table and insert proper `TEXT` values.

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xdDQttt8uLwBGmA7Wq5Qkx/0).

If you keep the table's current data you will always have to cast the `BLOB`s values to `TEXT` (not `VARCHAR` because there is no such data type in SQLite, although it works because [*the type VARCHAR contains the string "CHAR" and is thus assigned TEXT affinity*](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#determination_of_column_affinity))

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't understand why dumping the DB used hex. I'll have to check data production side for the reasons for the insert as BLOB mess.